# Jquery hide after delete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to remove a whole displayed message block after I pressed 'delete'.

It just doesnt work at all...

What I have:

```
function DelPost(postid) {
    $.ajax({
        url: Cussion.BaseURL + "/dashboard/delpost",
        type: "POST",
        data: { postid: postid },
        success: function(data) {
          $('post_'+postid).remove();
            if(data == "ok") {
                toastr["success"]("Uw gepost bericht is verwijderd.", "Gelukt!");
            }else{
                toastr["error"]("Uw gepost bericht is niet verwijderd.", "Er ging iets mis!");
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And My HTML:

```
@foreach($posts as $post)
      <div class="row row-sm" id="post_{!! $post->PostID !!}">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-heading">
              <a href class="pull-left w-32 m-r" href="{!! url(Auth::user()->slug) !!}">
                <img src="{!! asset('avatars/'.$post->image) !!}" class="w-full img-circle">
              </a>


              <div class="card-tools">
                <ul class="list-inline">
                  <li class="dropdown">
                    <a md-ink-ripple data-toggle="dropdown" class="md-btn md-flat md-btn-circle">
                      <i class="mdi-navigation-more-vert text-md"></i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-scale pull-right pull-up top text-color">
                      <li id="{!! $post->PostID !!}"><a onclick="DelPost({!! $post->PostID !!});"> <i class="material-icons i-24" style="font-size:15px;">delete</i> Verwijderen</a></li>
                      <li id="{!! $post->PostID !!}"><a onclick="alert('Niet beschikbaar.');"> <i class="material-icons i-24" style="font-size:15px;">edit</i> Beweken</a></li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>

              <div class="clear">
                <a href="{!! url($post->slug) !!}" class="font-bold block">{!! ucwords($post->firstname) !!} {!! ucwords($post->lastname) !!}</a> 
                <div class="text-xxs font-thin text-muted">{!! \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $post->PostAt)->diffForHumans() !!}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <!-- ONDERSTE MAG ENKEL WEERGEGEVEN WORDEN ALS DE AUTEUR EEN AFBEELDING HEEFT BIJGEVOEGD -->
            <!--<div class="item">
              <img src="PATH NAAR AFBEELDING" class="w-full" alt="Afbeelding">
            </div>

            <a md-ink-ripple="" class="md-btn md-raised md-fab  red m-r md-fab-offset pull-right bg-red waves-effect"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size:22px;padding-top:12px;color:white;">favorite</i></a>-->
            <!-- BOVENSTAANDE A TAG MOET EEN LIKE KNOP VOORSTELLEN -->
            <!-- HIER EINDIGT HET STUK DAT ENKEL MAG WEERGEGEVEN WORDEN WANNEER ER EEN FOTO BIJGEVOEGD IS! -->
            <div class="card-body">
              <p>
                {!! nl2br(e($post->description)) !!}
              </p>
              <p style="color:grey;font-size:10px;">Aantal likes - {!! \Cussion\SocialReaction::where('post_id', $post->PostID)->count() !!} {!! (\Cussion\SocialReaction::where('post_id', $post->PostID)->count() == 1) ? 'reactie' : 'reacties' !!} </p>
              <p style="font-size:14px;">Leuk vinden</p> <!-- KNOP OM STATUS TE LIKEN -->
            </div>

            <div class="list-group no-radius no-border" style="background-color:#F5F5F5;">

@foreach($comments as $comment)
@if($comment->post_id == $post->PostID)
              <div class="md-list-item">
                <div class="md-list-item-left">
                  <img src="{!! asset('avatars/'.$comment->image) !!}" class="w-full circle">
                </div>
                  <div class="md-list-item-content">
                    <small class="font-thin">{!! ucwords($comment->firstname) !!} {!! ucwords($comment->lastname) !!}</small>
                    <div class="text-xxs font-thin text-muted" style="font-size:12px;">{!! nl2br(e($comment->description)) !!}</div>
                    <div class="text-xxs font-thin text-muted" style="font-size:10px;">{!! \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $comment->PostAt)->diffForHumans() !!}</div>
                  </div>                
              </div>
@endif
@endforeach

              <div class="md-list-item">
              <form action="{!! url('/dashboard') !!}" method="post" role="form">
                {!! csrf_field() !!}
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Wat wil je reageren?">

                  <input type="hidden" name="post_id" value="{!! $post->PostID !!}">

                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Reageer</button>
                    </span>
                </div>
                </form>
              </div>

            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
@endforeach
```

So what I acctually want to do is,

deleting that whole HTML code..

So when I press 'delete', it must remove the post visible for the user.

I already tried alot to do, but nothing works and I can't figer it out.

It would be nice if it had some effects, but not necessary.

Thanks!

Comment: In addition to Alon's answer, if you want a simple slideUp or fadeOut animation when deleting you could do something like `$('#post_'+postid).slideUp(function() { $('#post_'+postid).remove(); });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot the ID selector part (`#`) - `$('post_'+postid).remove();` Should be changed to `$('#post_'+postid).remove();`